# Did Gus deliberately give motel where Nacho was holed up's phone number to Bolsa?

Tags: better-call-saul

In BCS 6/2 Carrot and Stick, Mike (working on behalf of Gus) plants stuff in new safe in Nacho's house, including a phone number. It is implied that he intends for the cartel to find it and they do. Bolsa calls the number and motel desk answers with the name of the motel. This gives the Cartel a reason to look into the motel and as a result, the Twins show up and almost catch Nacho. Why was this done by Gus and why would Mike go along with it if indeed Gus wanted it?

Comment: This is actually a good question. Given Mike's professed respect for Nacho, it does strike me as odd that he would go along with that plan. Also, the fact that if the cartel took Nacho alive then he might be tortured into revealing Gus' part in harming the Salamanca's interests and the assassination attempt on Lalo. Gus is a very careful man and the only risks he is shown taking are carefully calculated. As far as I can recall, the show doesn't address Mike or Gus' thought processes behind what went on here.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly right: Nacho was a millisecond-decision from being captured at the motel and then tortured -- the only very subtle thing that occurs to me is that perhaps someone wanted to bring down Gus -- it could not have been Mike because Mike liked Nacho; maybe Tyrus but I do not find that too convincing.

Comment: I don't think Tyrus would do anything like that without a go-ahead from Gus.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Yeah and also, Tyrus would probably be killed by cartel without Gus, not inherit his empire. This thing simply does not make sense, worst idea ever and there is no way it was not planned. He was so close to being caught: in the motel parking lot or even in the oil truck -- one of the Twins was literally with 20 feet of him and I believe Nacho was holding his breathe which could have expired any second while the Twin was watching.

Comment: Added some context in an edit, releasable. I think you were getting downvoted because there were some things you did not make clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Gus want the cartel to find Nacho?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117367/why-does-gus-want-the-cartel-to-find-nacho)

Answer (score 4):

### It was a gamble, but here's the logic (I think)

Giving the cartel Nacho's location in the form of the phone number and then telling Nacho to stay at the motel, *definitely* runs the risk of Nacho getting captured an tortured into giving up Gus, *but* there are two things that mitigate that risk:

1. The provide Nacho with a gun, which makes it much less likely that he will be taken alive. Nacho could force the cartel to kill him in self defense. Further, he knows what awaits him if he gets captured, so he would be very likely to kill himself if cornered.
2. Nacho knows what Gus will do to his father is he gives up Gus.

The phone number was not the only thing in the safe. There was also a paper record of a bank statement that I believe was supposed to make it look like Nacho took payment from a third party--Alvarez and Los Odios from Peru. This is more evidence pointing away from Gus.

Comment: Further to point #1, note that Nacho very nearly *does* get killed when the Salamancas come for him;  one of cousins shoots his own henchman to keep him from killing Nacho.